# Sending MIME multipart message with Send-mailmessage

Tags: powershell, mime

Simple question but so far I can't figure out.

Is it possible to send an email multipart MIME message with send-mailmessage powershell cmdlet ?

Purpose is to embed inline images.

Thank you

Comment: Please note that Send-MailMessage is obsolete, even if there is no immediate workaround! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out following PS module that fulfils my need : InlineMailAttachments.psm1 . It required some tuning, mainly for UTF-8 body content, but was operational in matter of minutes.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/InlineMailAttachments/1.0/Content/InlineMailAttachments.psm1

Answer (score 0):

You can employ the .NET System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class for constructing and transmitting an email together with inline images.

Here's an illustration:

```
# Variables
$smtpServer = "smtp.yourserver.com"
$smtpPort = 587
$emailFrom = "sender@example.com"
$emailTo = "recipient@example.com"
$subject = "Subject Text"
$body = @"
This is an example email that includes an inline image.<br>
<img src="cid:MyInlineImage">
"@
$smtpUser = "smtpUser"
$smtpPass = "smtpPassword"
$imagePath = "C:\path\to\your\image.jpg"

# Create a new MailMessage object
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.From = $emailFrom
$message.To.Add($emailTo)
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.IsBodyHtml = $true
$message.Body = $body

# Create a new Attachment object for the inline image
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment -ArgumentList $imagePath
$attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $true
$attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
$attachment.ContentId = "MyInlineImage"
$message.Attachments.Add($attachment)

# Create a new SmtpClient object and send the email
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, $smtpPort)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($smtpUser, $smtpPass)
$smtp.Send($message)

# Clean up
$message.Dispose()
$attachment.Dispose()
```

This script will dispatch an email alongside the image as an inline attachment. The img element within the HTML body references the ContentId of the attachment, which renders the image exhibit inline within the email body.

This script moreover presumes that you require authenticating alongside the SMTP server. If you don't necessitate authentication, you can eliminate the line that establishes the Credentials property.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: This code sends parsed message with inline images, not a raw MIME message. Please validate an OpenAI response before posting it.